# Convert 1 and 0 from command line to True or False in Python script

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
import sys
def main(option1, option2, option3): 
   # do something

if __name__ == '__main__':
   option1 = bool(sys.argv[1])
   option2 = bool(sys.argv[2])
   option3 = bool(sys.argv[3])
```

However, when I run the script from command line as:

```
conda activate myenv
python C:\mypath\myscript.py 0 0 1
```

It does not convert the integers to booleans and runs as if all were True (1s). Does anyone how can I fix this?

Comment: the input are strings (`bool('0')` -> `True`), you need to convert: `bool(int(sys.argv[1]))`  (NB. this is a simple example, you probably need to validate the input first)

Answer (score 1):

In python a a non-empty string is "truthy", meaning it evaluates as true when used as a condition. `argv` elements are always strings, so you're getting the "truthiness" of 3 non-empty strings here, which will always evaluate as true.

You should convert to int before converting to bool.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
   option1 = bool(int(sys.argv[1]))
   option2 = bool(int(sys.argv[2]))
   option3 = bool(int(sys.argv[3]))
```

Comment: Thanks, this solves it.

Comment: Thanks @khelwood I updated my answer to be more technically accurate.